# Extract JSON array values with generic keys to JSON_TABLE in uniform columns

Tags: sql, mysql, arrays, json, json-table

I have JSON that is being brought into MariaDB/MYSQL database via Airbyte from a API query. I am using JSON_TABLE to break the JSON into columns - which is *mostly* working great, but I just noticed that there is an array of JSON elements that changes from time to time. Rather than using unique keypairs, they are sending generic keypairs, for example:

```js
{
  "id": 123,
  "position": "North",
  "attributes": [{
    "name": "First Name",
    "value": "Santa"
  }, {
    "name": "Last Name",
    "value": "Claus"
  }]
}
```

The elements can appear in any order so I can't target them with my JSON_TABLE query:

```sql
SELECT t.id, t.position, t.firstName, t.lastName 
FROM
    (
    mytable
    JOIN JSON_TABLE(mytable, '$'
    COLUMNS (
            id int(10) PATH '$.id',
            position varchar(20) PATH '$.position',
            firstName varchar(20) PATH '$.attributes[0].value',
            lastName varchar(20) PATH '$.attributes[1].value'
            )
          ) t
     )
```

How can I handle the attributes returning in a dynamic order?

Also, the amount of elements may change as well, so whatever i use to target the elements must fail gracefully if the elements don't exist.

My plan  was to utilize JSON_SEARCH, so search for the object name = "First Name" then return the value to the element. I cannot figure out how to do this within a JSON_TABLE Query. I've tried:

```
First Name varchar(20) PATH REPLACE(JSON_SEARCH('$.attributes', 'all', 'First Name'), '.name', '.value'))
```

Which in a standard query will return the element path. However i need to dynamically build a JSON_TABLE for this to work properly. I get a SQL error near REPLACE(JSON_SEARCH which I don't have a working example to compare against.

Comment: So you just want to extract the values corresponding to first name and last name?

Comment: @SalmanA Those are simply examples. I will have between 5-10 sets of values. but i want to line them up in a columnar fashion. 

| First Name | Last Name| Address | Phone | etc....| 

The order of which may change, How can i use something dynamic to gather the correct values for the given columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use `json_table` to convert the `$.attributes` array into rows. You could use the nested path clause, a sub query inside select, etc. Rest is straight forward:

```sql
select
    t.pk,
    jt.id,
    jt.position,
    min(case when jt.name = 'first name' then jt.value end) as fname,
    min(case when jt.name = 'last name' then jt.value end) as lname
from t
cross join json_table(
    t.js,
    '$' columns (
        id int path '$.id',
        position varchar(20) path '$.position',
        nested path '$.attributes[*]' columns (
            name varchar(20) path '$.name',
            value varchar(20) path '$.value'
        )
    )
) as jt
group by t.pk, jt.id, jt.position
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XmW9Rcuq)

Comment: This is looking better, however i am confused about the "group by t.pk...." there are no columns called t.pk, what is that doing?

Also do i have to group EVERY column?

Edit, disregard, i have it working now, This is amazing! Thank you.

Comment: its the primary key of the table. In the revised dbfiddle, there is another example that does not use group by.